# Setting a SpriteKit Node's Position (Mid-Game)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using **Sprite Kit and Swift 2**, and am currently having a problem with setting the position of my Nodes to a very specific spot mid-game. For example, if I click a button I want the player's position to become (50,50).

However when I try using

```
player.position = CGPointMake(50,50)
```

Nothing happens. I've seen that people have said this a bug that is fixed by adding the line:

```
player.physicsBody = player.physicsBody
```

However this does nothing for me. I have also tried doing:

```
player.position.x = 50
player.position.y = 50
```

But this also does nothing :(.

Also here is the player's decleration:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blue")
player.name = "player"
player.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)
addChild(player)
player.size = CGSize(width: ogSquareSize!, height: ogSquareSize!)
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true;
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
player.physicsBody?.mass = 15;
```

Like I said it moves normally, and I can see it, and it interacts with the scene normally, but if I try to directly change its position nothing happens.

Here is where I try to call my code to change its position:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
        switch(contactMask) {
        case playerCategory | object2Category:

            let player = childNodeWithName("player") as! SKSpriteNode
            player.position.y += 100;

        default:
            return
        }
    }
```

Basically what is going on here is I'm telling it to move its position upward by 100 if it collides with another object (Im not trying to do artificial colliding I actually have a pretty good reason for moving it upward like this).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do  you see your player at all, but you just can't  reposition it (or player is not visible in the scene)? Also, a bit more context would be helpful (eg. what is the player's parent node, does player have physics body, how do you move it etc.)

Comment: @Whirlwind yes the object is pretty standard and is a child of the scene. You can see it and it acts normally, but when I try to give it a specific position it just doesn't move to that spot. I'll add its declaration to the question too.

Comment: If possible, you should try to add a minimal example which can reproduce what you are saying ...

Comment: @Whirlwind I added the code I used to declare it. After that I load it into the scene, and it falls to the ground like normal. When I run the code to change its position, its as if I didn't run the code to change where it is. (It then continues to act in the scene normally).

Comment: It works for me with the code you have provided... Also, you should keep in mind that mix of physics simulation & changing node's position manually is bad idea in almost every case (you are pulling the node out of physics simulation). Still, that is not the problem here, and you should be able to reposition your node. Like I said,  if you can provide a minimal example which can reproduce what you are saying, I could tell more.

Comment: @Whirlwind I see what you mean now - if I try it in other areas of my code it works. I've now added where I call it, hopefully a red flag pops up there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103443/discussion-between-whirlwind-and-marshalld).

Comment: So is that case executed at all ? Try to put a print("executed") in the body of that particular case...

Comment: Have you tried to change the position in the didSimulatePhysics method?

Comment: @Stefan yes and it works there, but I need to run the code here.

Comment: What, if you fill a global variable with the new position in didBeginContact and change the position in didSimulatePhysics?

Comment: @Stefan well now I feel like an idiot.. I got that to work now - You should make that into an answer

Comment: I've added this as an answer. Good to hear that this solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill a global variable with the new position in

> didBeginContact

and change the position in

> didSimulatePhysics